# Unflatten Arrays into groups of fours

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array that is as follows:

```
var someArray = ['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9','val10','val11','val12'];
```

I'm trying to figure out some elegant way, using `underscore`, of simply converting it to an array of arrays like so...

```
[['val1','val2','val3','val4'], ['val5','val6','val7','val8'], ['val9','val10','val11','val12']]
```

Where each index of the new array is groups of four elements from the first array.  Is there an easy elegant way of doing this with `underscore.js`.

Comment: Thanks people.  I already have a plain JS solution.  I wanted to see if there was some standard function in underscore that was even simpler.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Underscore, since you asked:** ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5VKZ5/1/))

```
var i = 4, list = _.groupBy(someArray, function(a, b){
    return Math.floor(b/i);
});
newArray = _.toArray(list);
```

**Vanilla JS:** ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5VKZ5/2/))

```
var newArray = [], size = 4;
while (someArray.length > 0) newArray.push(someArray.splice(0, size));
```

Answer (score 7):

Pure JavaScript solution, using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, 'eachConsecutive', {
  value:function(n){
    var copy = this.concat(), result = [];
    while (copy.length) result.push( copy.splice(0,n) );
    return result;        
  }
});

var someArray = ['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9','val10','val11','val12'];
var chunked = someArray.eachConsecutive(4);
//-> [["val1","val2","val3","val4"],["val5","val6","val7","val8"],["val9","val10","val11","val12"]]
```

Comment: Downvote because tampering with prototype